# How to use a rewrite rule to redirect to https but relative?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

Is there a way to redirect to a specific page but adding https and keeping the path relative at the same time?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]+)/settings/?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/settings/settings.php?u=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The above works well but it's somehow absolute as we start with `https://%{HTTP_HOST}`
And this makes the end URL to show the exact request: https://www.mydomain.com/settings/settings.php?u=John

Can we, instead, redirect to a page, adding https in a relative way? so that the exact path keeps being hidden and we only see a "folder structure": https://www.mydomain.com/user/John/settings

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trick is to do `http->https` (R=301) rule on pretty URL before rewriting it internally. So something like this would work:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^user/([^/]+)/settings/?$ /settings/settings.php?u=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```